# Does "soluble in alcohol" imply ethanol?

Tags: solubility, alcohols

Sources like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_acetate) and [SolubilityOfThings](http://www.solubilityofthings.com/copper-ii-acetate) say that copper (II) acetate is soluble in alcohol.

Does that mean any alcohol, or does "alcohol" in this context mean ethanol?

Comment: Well, unless noted otherwise it should mean that. This compound should be also soluble in methanol or glycol, but not in long chain alcohols.

Comment: Sound like they meant ethanol, but the substance will be soluble in other alcohols too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The term "alcohol", without modification (i.e. "propyl" alcohol, etc.), in the context of something like a solubility table, almost always refers to ethanol (as it does in your sources for copper (II) acetate solubility).

Note, for example, that both [pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/702#section=Top) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol) list *alcohol* as a synonym for *ethanol*. This is not the case for other alcohols like isopropanol.